# How can I simplify multiple update SQL commands as a single SQL command?

Tags: sql, sql-update, where-clause

My condition : I need to update same column name:

```
UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 0 
WHERE condition_from_value = 0;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 0.501 
WHERE condition_from_value = 501;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 1.001 
WHERE condition_from_value = 1001;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate   
SET condition_from_value = 1.501 
WHERE condition_from_value = 1501;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 2.001 
WHERE condition_from_value = 2001;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 2.501 
WHERE condition_from_value= 2501;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 3.001 
WHERE condition_from_value= 3001;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 3.501 
WHERE condition_from_value = 3501;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 4.001 
WHERE condition_from_value = 4001;

UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = 4.501 
WHERE condition_from_value = 4501;
```

How can I run this as a single SQL command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an "IN" operator and divide by 1000:

```
UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value = condition_from_value / 1000.00 
WHERE condition_from_value IN (0, 501, 1001, 1501, 2001, 2501, 3001, 3501, 4001, 4501);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if you want to update all rows where the value is 0, 1, 501, 1001, etc.

Add upper/lower limits to the WHERE clause if needed.

```
UPDATE shipping_matrixrate
SET condition_from_value= condition_from_value / 1000.0
WHERE condition_from_value % 500 = 1 or condition_from_value = 0
```

`%` is a common modulo operator. However, ANSI SQL specifies the `MOD()` function for modulo. I.e. do `MOD(condition_from_value, 500) = 1`.

Comment: What if the RDBMS in question doesn't have the `%` modulo operator?

Answer (score 0):

Divide the value by 1000

```
UPDATE shipping_matrixrate 
SET condition_from_value= condition_from_value/1000 
WHERE ( condition_from_value <= 4501 and 
 condition_from_value%500 = 1) 
or condition_from_value =0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the case command

```
Update shipping_matrixrate
Set condition_from_value  =  
Case When condition_from_value = 0 Then 0
     When condition_from_value = 501 Then 0.501
     When ...
End
```